# Magento 2 in how to add the attributes extra more then values in bulk import ? what is th csv formats?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, csv

drop down box values not working  in admin panel side using bulk import..!

[image]

products attributes values not working in bulk import in csv files ?

Comment: Hi Mr.Sudhakar....You want to import your product csv file with your custom attribute right

Comment: custom attributes will be created but values not added .

Comment: Okiee....if you export csv file you can able to find and edit your custom attribute and you are facing issue while import csv file right

Comment: export file only one file but i have 3 files in separated in products attributes and products and products attributes values. values only not be added..!

Comment: Check with my answer it will helpfull for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is new another issues for admin panel side .

attributes values will be set the particular size and length, thats for values not will be imported

attributes values maximum values size 31 characters. and drop down option will be more then not accepted.ex(1500).

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 -  When you are export product csv,created product custom attributes comes under "additional_attributes" column in csv file .

**If you have multiple custom attribute,which would be separated by commas in same "additional_attributes" column**

**additional_attributes** column in product csv file

```
Product 1 : attribute_code1 = custom_attribute_value1 , attribute_code2 = custom_attribute_value2 , gon on...
Product 2 : attribute_code1 = custom_attribute_value1 , attribute_code2 = custom_attribute_value2 , go on...
```

Finally you can proceed normal magento2 import process,you can see respective product attributes value are updated...

**Notes : Magento 2 custom attributes value comes under "additional_attributes" column in csv file**

Comment: @Sudhakar it will help for you...

Comment: Ok , i will try  Mr. AjithKumar

Comment: Okay,if you are facing any issue let me know with clear definition

Comment: Did you got result Mr.Sudhakar